# What is a good way to manage sliding views like the iPhone IMDB app?

Tags: ios, view

The IMDB app for iPhone seems to allow infinite drill downs and explorations from a movie detail page to a detail page of an actor who was in that movie, to that actor's first movie to that movie's director, etc.

What is the best way to build this in Xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to check out Apple's `UINavigationController` documentation/sample  code [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can learn a lot about iOS development from looking at the sample apps.

The "infinite drill down" you're referring to is the act of "pushing" a controller onto the current stack of controllers. As you go back, you "pop" a controller off the stack to get back to the previous controller. If implemented properly, `UINavigationController` will handle things like making sure the Back button contains the title of the previous screen, keeping the screens in order, and the sliding motion.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can create by using a `UINavigationController` and push the view one by one as you want.